# solution to differential equation

Tags: r, differential-equations

This is a very basic question related to solving differential equation (DE) in R:

I am using deSolve package to solve DE.

`dX <- a*X + a*b`

The problem is that I want to evaluate the solution at time (based on my time column) and corresponding b value (b values is different at each time).

Here's my code:

```
parameters <- c(a=1.3714)
state <- c(X=0)
Lorenz <- function(t, state, parameters) {
  with(as.list(c(state, parameters)), {
    # rate of change
    b <- c(PD$blood)
    dX <- a*X + a*b
    # return the rate of change
    list(dX)
  })

}
times <- PD$time

head(times)
library(deSolve)
out <- ode(y = state, times = times, func = Lorenz, parms = parameters)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I totally understand the question, and it would help to provide some example data, but you can define a function (fun_dyn_b) that calls the b value at time t as defined in the Lorenz function:

```
parameters <- c(a=1.3714)
state <- c(X=0)
func_dyn_b <- function(t) PD$blood[t]

Lorenz <- function(t, state, parameters) {
  with(as.list(c(state, parameters)), {
    # rate of change
    b <- func_dyn_b(t)
    dX <- a*X + a*b
    # return the rate of change
    list(dX)
  })

}
times <- PD$time

head(times)
library(deSolve)
out <- ode(y = state, times = times, func = Lorenz, parms = parameters)
```

Hope that helps.

---

It looks like your times do not have uniform intervals, and therefore my solution wouldn't work, since time would need to be in increments of 1, starting at 1 (so it could be used as a index).  I would suggest looking more into your time intervals and seeing if you can figure out what the exact time interval (0.0033 sec. or something?) and thinking of a way to implement func_dyn_b() so it calls the right b at the correct time.

Good luck.